# Nested attributes query on DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, nested, amazon-dynamodb

I have something like this on Dynamo:

```js
{
    "mail": "user@anonymous.com",
    "data": {
        "type": 1
    }
}
```

I have an index on "mail" attribute and I'm trying to query over all data found with an specified mail filtering the attribute "data". Something like this:

```js
const params = {
    TableName: 'tableName',
    IndexName: "mail_index",
    KeyConditionExpression: "#mail = :mail",
    FilterExpression: '#status = :val',
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
        '#mail': 'mail',
        '#status': 'data.type'
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ':mail': 'user@anonymous.com',
        ':val': {N: 5}
    } 
};

dynamoDoc.query(params, (err, data) => {
    console.log(data);
});
```

But I'm always getting an empty result. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```js
const params = {
    TableName: 'tableName',
    IndexName: "mail_index",
    KeyConditionExpression: "#mail = :mail",
    FilterExpression: '#data.#type = :val',
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
        '#mail': 'mail',
        '#data': 'data',
        '#type': 'type'
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ':mail': 'user@anonymous.com',
        ':val': {N: 5}
    } 
};
```

Because both `data` and `type` are [reserved words](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ReservedWords.html), DynamoDB needs both of them to be escaped.

Comment: Thx! Worked for me